# Wait for event.on() function to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, socket.io

I have this code, and the function I essentially want is to run the function, and have all my code wait until the function has finished executing before continuing to execute the switch. Is there any way to wait until the promise or .on() statement is actually triggered before going to the switch statement? Currently, it will execute itself with the promise pending, not waiting for it to be fulfilled. I'm using node.js, socket.io and express currently. If this is not possible, then another node plugin would be appreciated that would enable this to work.

I'm making a poker web app btw so each turn is dependant upon the last player's turn.

```
_bettingPhase() {

    var index = 0;
    var pArray = this._playerArray;
    var standingBet = 0;

    async function getAction(index, playerArray) {
        var turn = null;
      let myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
            playerArray[index].id.once('turn', (turn) => {
            resolve(turn);
            })
      });
      turn = await myPromise;
      console.log('getAction run');
      return(turn);
    }

    this._playerArray[index].action = getAction(index, pArray);

    switch(this._playerArray[index].action) { 

        case 'raise': 
            this._playerArray[index].money -= this._playerArray[index].amount + standingBet; 
            standingBet = this._playerArray[index].amount;
        case 'call': 
            this._playerArray[index].money -= this._playerArray[index].amount;
    }
```

Comment: No. That's the whole point of the Promise mechanism: the code you want to happen after resolution is in a `.then()` callback or after the `await`.

Comment: Note that your code calls `getAction()`, an asynchronous function, without using `await`.

Comment: The part that code you refer to is under a function that can't be async, I assumed that awaiting for the promise would in turn make the function wait since the return value is paired to the action of awaiting the promise. 

I have multiple players, each player's action is dependant upon the previous player's action. Does this mean I will have an insane amount of .then() callbacks to run? Should I have instead coded my serverside with a different language? (not too late to change I guess)

Comment: It's best to stick with `async` and `await`, because it's clearer. You cannot under any circumstances make an asynchronous operation behave synchronously. The point of `async` and `await` is to make it possible to write code *as if* the asynchronous operations were synchronous, but they still are not.

Comment: awesome thanks, I'll see if there is another way to design the app.

Comment: What's wrong with adding `await` so you have this: `this._playerArray[index].action = await getAction(index, pArray);`?  You will have to make it be `async _bettingPhase()`, but other than that, it looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: And, you can remove `turn = await myPromise;` and just do `return myPromise` instead since that `await` isn't doing anything useful.  `getAction()` returns a promise either way since ALL `async` functions return a promise.