# Wait for .on() to be fulfilled, not pending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

My desired output is for  this._playerArray[index].action to actually have the player's action. I had hoped that writing "await getAction()" would stop my code from running. The problem is, the promise is pending and the code doesn't care to wait until it is fulfilled until moving on.

Is there any way to code this so that my code will wait until the promise is fulfilled, ie the event being emitted from the client side? Note that the code runs so fast that the player doesn't get to input anything.

The code below outputs "promise {  }", the player's action is "undefined", then "bettingPhase finish"

```
    async _bettingPhase() {
        var index = 0;
        var pArray = this._playerArray;

        function getAction(index, playerArray) {
            var action = null;
          let myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
                playerArray[index].id.on('turn', (turn) => {
                resolve(turn);
                })
          });
          console.log(myPromise);
        }

         this._playerArray[index].action = await getAction(index, pArray);
         console.log(this._playerArray);
         console.log('bettingPhase finish');

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to do `return myPromise` in `getAction` ?

Comment: ever try to break that function into some part? so after function a getting result it will pass an argument to function b then continue to another function until all done.

Comment: Also, probably best to change `.on()` to `.once()` since promises only ever resolve once anyway.

Comment: OneQ, I am so dumb, I literally spent 3 days trying to figure out how to achieve that, only tried this code today but still. tysm lol

Comment: Wasn't this [answered in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971823/wait-for-event-on-function-to-complete?noredirect=1#comment132305217_74971823) already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return your promise in your `getAction` function.

Like this :

```
function getAction(index, playerArray) {
    var action = null;
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        playerArray[index].id.on('turn', (turn) => {
            resolve(turn);
        })
    });
    return myPromise;
}
```